Using "Each time" with the present progressive
Is it totally impossible to use the present progressive like this :

Each time you are throwing the ball you are damaging my flowers

Thank you very much for your opinion

Yes, impossible. Right.

Few things are "totally impossible." There's nothing grammatically wrong with this sentence. It's just that simple present, or a combination of simple present for the first verb with progressive for the second, is more likely.

@AndyBonner It is a misuse of the progressive tense. Ergo, a mistake. There is nothing wrong with stating that outright.

Most British native speakers would either think it clumsy or an outright mistake and prefer "Each time you throw the ball you damage my flowers". Using the present progressive like that is widespread in India, I gather.

@Lambie I don't claim to speak for any other speakers than British ones. I don't think native speakers in Canada, the US, Australia, South Africa, New Zealand, or anywhere else 'native speaking' would say it.

Basically, Indian English often uses present progressive where BrE and AmE use simple present. It's a dialect thing. I don't know how true it is in actuality, but it's used frequently in caricatures to highlight a character's Indianness.

@Barmar It is not a dialect thing. In good English medium schools they would correct such a usage.

@JamesMathai Where does it come from? Is it related to a direct translation of Hindi conjugation?

@MichaelHarvey That last statement is right. No native speaker of English would use it. Brit or otherwise.

Thank you very much

I told students that it was correct and then I realized it wasn't I don't know how to correct this without losing my credibility

It's in an exercise

"To BE _____ing"  expresses action-in-progress.
That in-progress aspect conflicts with "each time", which isolates each instance of the action in a kind of "freeze-frame", a  snapshot of it.  In-progress and frozen are contradictory aspects.
So the  clausal complement of "each time" has to be in a simple tense or a perfect tense:

Each time I see her...
Each time I saw her...
Each time I've seen her...
Each time you throw that ball...
Each time you threw that ball...
Each time you've thrown that ball...

The main clause can be in the progressive/continuous:

Each time I saw her, she was watering her garden.

etc

Thank you very much for all your answers
